# Spawning multiple objects using ARkit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

How do I spawn more then one type of enemy? The way they are labeled are small, medium and large.

```
 func spawnAlien(numAliens: Int) -> Alien?{ // Decides whether an alien should be spawned
    guard numAliens < maxAliens else { return nil }
    spawnCount += 1
    if(spawnCount == spawnFreq){
        spawnCount = 0
        if(arc4random_uniform(spawnProb) == 0){
            return Alien(health: 1, power: 1, shotFreq: 60, shotProbHigh: 10, shotProbLow: 2, type: .small)

        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your this function here
`return Alien(health: 1, power: 1, shotFreq: 60, shotProbHigh: 10, shotProbLow: 2, type: .small)`
is only taking `.small`.

You can probably change this to `.medium` or `.large`.

If you want to randomly spawn different types, you can use another `arc4random_uniform` to determine random type it would be.

```
var typeToBeRandomized = .small
let randomValue = arc4random_uniform(3)

if randomValue == 1 {
typeToBeRandomized = .medium
} else if randomValue == 2 {
typeToBeRandomized = .large
}
```

Now pass this `typeToBeRandomized` to your above Alien constructor, instead of a hardcoded `.small`

Comment: how would I go about using arc4random_uniform to include the small, medium and large enemy?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform(3)` This will give you values between 0 to 2. You can use an `if/else` and give the appropriate type to your alien.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I'm getting confused.

Comment: which bit are you confused about?

Comment: I barely started learning to code so I don't really know how to use arc4random_uniform(3) or use and if/else to spawn the other enemies.

Comment: In that case, you should definitely read the Swift book on iBooks. That will be a really good stepping stone.